# query count returns Resource id # as a result instead of a number

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting a Resource id # as a result. The query returns the right count when using myphpadmin. 
I have tried using mysql_fetch_assoc, and mysql_fetch_row but I can't get it to work. 
Could use some guidance. Thank you.

### note: $casenumber reflects the case number from a different table

```
$casenumber= ($rows['case_number']);  //stores this rows case number

$casecount = "SELECT COUNT(case_number) AS `total`  
FROM `vekt6_chronoforms_data_CaseJuryPool`\n"
    . "WHERE vekt6_chronoforms_data_CaseJuryPool.case_number = '{$casenumber}'";

$num = mysql_query($casecount);

echo $num; // result of case numbers count
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php#71793 This may help you as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to fetch your results

```
$res = mysql_query($casecount);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['total'];
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: That worked. I have a similar problem with the query below. It echos the word Array instead of a number.

$uniquejuror = "SELECT COUNT(`case_number`) AS `total2`
FROM `vekt6_chronoforms_data_CaseJuryPool` 
WHERE `vekt6_chronoforms_data_CaseJuryPool.case_juror` = '{$uid}';
AND `vekt6_chronoforms_data_CaseJuryPool.case_number` = '{$casenumber}'";

$uj = mysql_query($uniquejuror);
$rowuj = mysql_fetch_assoc($uj);
echo $rowuj['total2'];